# I receive messages, but they are not displayed at statusbar(my app is in the background 100%)

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I migrated the project to FCM from GCM. Already made changes on the server side and updated all dependencies in the mobile application. But when I receive a message, it does not appear in the status bar, and I cannot understand why.

```
    <service
        android:name="com.SkinPhd.Olympus.fcm.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
    }

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message getNotification == null");
    }
}
```

> Logcat:
>
> MyFirebaseMsgService: From: 413140669797
>
> MyFirebaseMsgService: Message data payload: {push_id=962, type_item=0, message=Hello. This is a test push., item_id=-1}
>
> MyFirebaseMsgService: Message getNotification == null

Why remoteMessage.getNotification() == null?
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

A solution was found: it turned out that not everything is so simple with the transition to a new platform, and backward compatibility does not work as well as our "good corporation" writes about it. It was necessary to alter the server-side logic specifically how the documentation is written, and not as simple as the documentation on migration to FCM.